# Upsert + Oplog tailing

Tags: meteor, upsert

```
Meteor.publish("Rows", ->
  return [] unless @userId
  Rows.find({userId: @userId})
)
```

In Meteor 1.1.0.2, when I do...

```
Rows.update(selector, modifier)
```

... the changes are sent to the client immediately (yay!) But when I do...

```
Rows.upsert(selector, modifier)
```

... the changes are sent after a small delay (presumably after the polling driver picks them up).

Am I doing something wrong, or is it just a limitation of current oplog tailing driver?

Comment: Fascinating! One of my coworkers suspects `upsert` is generally less efficient than `update`--I think he said it often ends up doing `remove` _and_ `insert`. Will you add more information? For example: what version of Meteor are you using? Also, will you include [benchmarks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/benchmark) of the `update` and `upsert` calls?

Comment: @AdamMonsen I'm using Meteor 1.1.0.2. Actually, the problem isn't related to upsert performance, but rather to Meteor oplog performance in regard to upsert operation. I doubt benchmarks on upsert itself would help. However, it's interesting: do you have the same problem as well?

Comment: The upsert will either enter an 'update' or an 'insert' line in the oplog.  An 'update' entry from an upsert is indistinguishable from an 'update' entry from an update.  You can view oplog entries by with `meteor mongo` using the 'local' db and running `db.oplog.rs.find()`.  Polling vs observing the oplog is determined by the cursor being observed not by the command used to modify the db.

Comment: @user728291, you're totally right. Then why does the client only see the changes after a delay?